# Minimize the average distance from each cities to the closest hospitals

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, pseudocode

There are n cities [1, 2, 3, .... n] and k available hospitals. k < n. We need to place hospitals into the cities. How to place these hospitals to minimize the average distance from each cities to the closest hospitals.?

Right now my thought is using dynamic programming with a 2D array of size n * k. Then I know optimal solution will be
f(n, k) = [image], which pump is the position at the median of cities +1,...,. I believe this is the right approach but I do not know how to store the location of each hospitals. Please help

Comment: Just to check if I am understanding your problem correctly, Is your problem equivalent to minimizing the sum of the distances of each city to the closest hospital?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Yes!!!

Comment: First, note that the problem is called the $k$-median problem which NP-hard. So, you can not expect any algorithm with a running time polynomial in $n$ and $k$

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Hi, I believe my run time will be n^2k. the n * k is just the 2d array for me to build up the final solution

Comment: Secondly, what do you mean by the median of the cities? Is it [$1$-median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median). In that case, $pump_{k}$ might not be located at some city.

Comment: You can trivially find $n^k$ solution, by taking all possible $k$ subsets of hospitals and choosing that subset that gives you the minimum cost.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami That was I first approach, however, I want to optimize my solution now, and think that dynamic programming should be the right approach. My thought on the relationship is that f(i, j) is the minimum distance of using j hospitals to cover 1...I cities. Is this making sense?

Comment: Your DP solution is incorrect. You are missing many cases, for example when the first city and the last city are the only two cities assigned to the same hospital. This case is not covered in your recursion expression.